# Cakephp js helper form submit issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Property',array('id'=>'add_property'));?>

      <?$data = $this->Js->get('#add_property')->serializeForm(
                                        array(
                                        'isForm' => true,
                                        'inline' => true)
                                            );?>
           <? echo $this->Js->submit('submit.png',
        array('id'=>'submit_id',
            'update' => '#right_side_content', // element to update
            'data'=>$data,
        'before' => $this->Js->get('#submit_busy-indicator')->effect('fadeIn',      array('buffer' => false)),
   'complete' => $this->Js->get('#submit_busy-indicator')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),                       
 ));?>
```

Generates the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {$("#submit_id").bind("click", function (event)     {$.ajax({beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {$("#submit_busy-indicator").fadeIn();},  complete:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {$("#submit_busy-indicator").fadeOut();}, 
data:$("#submit_id").closest("form").serialize(), dataType:"html", success:function  (data, textStatus) {$("#right_side_content").html(data);}, type:"POST",  url:"\/cakeapp\/property\/add_property"});
return false;});});
```

Shouldn't this line:

```
data:$("#submit_id").closest("form").serialize(), dataType:"html"
```

be

```
data:$("#add_porperty").closest("form").serialize(), dataType:"html"
```

?

Comment: @ Simone,thanx for formatting the last two lines,was struggling with it.

Comment: My guess is that `$this->Js->submit(...` already generates JavaScript to serialize the form and prefers its 'own' data-key over the one you're passing. Personally, for reasons like this, I don't use the JsHelper to *generate* my jQuery code. Coding JavaScript by hand is easier to maintain and far more readable